# Qt Create with menubar and toolbar in a separate class file

Tags: c++, class, qt-creator, toolbar, menubar

I would like to create a GUI using Qt Creator, and have started a normal Qt Application Desktop project. To prevent the "MainWindow" class-files from getting too large, I would like to break out the menubar and toolbar in a separate class. I am new to Qt, and though I have searched high and low on Google, I haven't been able to find a suitable example. I am working in Qt 5.8.

What I have is:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "mwmenubar.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mwmenubar.h"

#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    // Now populate empty menubar & toolbar
    MWMenubar *MWmenu = new MWMenubar(this);
//    MWmenu->show();  // Shows a detached menubar (i.e. outside of the main window).

    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**mwmenubar.h**

```
#ifndef MWMENUBAR_H
#define MWMENUBAR_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QToolBar>

class QAction;
class QMenu;
class QToolBar;

class MWMenubar : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MWMenubar(QMainWindow *inMainWindow); // Constructor
    ~MWMenubar();                         // Destructor

private:
    QMainWindow  *mainWindow;

private slots:
    // Declare function prototypes
    void aFileNewCallback();
    void aFileOpenCallback();
    void aFileExitCallback();

private:
    // Declare function prototypes for creating actions and menus
    void createActions();
    void createMenus();
    void createToolbar();

    // Define menubar elements
    QMenu *mFile;

    // Define toolbar elements
    QToolBar *tFile;

    // Define menubar and toolbar actions
    QAction *aFileNew;
    QAction *aFileOpen;
    QAction *aFileExit;
};

#endif // MWMENUBAR_H
```

**mwmenubar.cpp**

```
#include "mwmenubar.h"
#include <QDebug>

MWMenubar::MWMenubar(QMainWindow *parent)
{
    mainWindow = parent;

    createActions(); // Create all individual menu actions
    createMenus();   // Create main window menubar
    createToolbar(); // Create main window toolbar
}

MWMenubar::~MWMenubar()
{
    // The destructor should not be needed, as the menubar is part of the
    // main window and will be deleted when the main window is closed.
}

// Create individual menu action callbacks
void MWMenubar::aFileNewCallback()
{
    qDebug() << "Pressing File->New!";
}

void MWMenubar::aFileOpenCallback()
{
    qDebug() << "Pressing File->Open!";
}

void MWMenubar::aFileExitCallback()
{
    qDebug() << "Pressing File->Exit!";
    mainWindow->close();
}

// Function for creating all menu actions
void MWMenubar::createActions()
{
//    const QIcon newIcon = QIcon::fromTheme("document-new", QIcon(":/images/new.png"));
//    aFileNew = new QAction(newIcon, tr("&New..."), this);
    aFileNew = new QAction(tr("&New..."), this);
    aFileNew->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::New);
    aFileNew->setStatusTip(tr("Create a new file"));
    connect(aFileNew, &QAction::triggered, this, &MWMenubar::aFileNewCallback);

//    const QIcon openIcon = QIcon::fromTheme("document-open", QIcon(":/images/open.png"));
//    aFileOpen = new QAction(openIcon, tr("&Open..."), this);
    aFileOpen = new QAction(tr("&Open..."), this);
    aFileOpen->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Open);
    aFileOpen->setStatusTip(tr("Open an existing file"));
    connect(aFileOpen, &QAction::triggered, this, &MWMenubar::aFileOpenCallback);

    aFileExit = new QAction(tr("E&xit"), this);
    aFileExit->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Quit);
    aFileExit->setStatusTip(tr("Exit the application"));
    connect(aFileExit, &QAction::triggered, this, &MWMenubar::aFileExitCallback);
}

void MWMenubar::createMenus()
{
    mFile = mainWindow->menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
    mFile->addAction(aFileNew);
    mFile->addAction(aFileOpen);
    mFile->addSeparator();
    mFile->addAction(aFileExit);
}

void MWMenubar::createToolbar()
{
    tFile = mainWindow->addToolBar(tr("File"));
    tFile->addAction(aFileNew);
    tFile->addAction(aFileOpen);
}
```

(For simplicity I have commented out the icons for the QActions ("New" and "Open")).

The toobar shows up fine, but I can't make the menubar show up. I have spent hours trying all sorts of things but in vain. So a code example would be greatly appreciated. I realize that what I am doing may be wrong alltogether - if so, please show me what to do.

Comment: You probably want `MWMenubar *MWmenu = new MWMenubar(this);` after `ui->setupUi(this);`

Comment: Also you may just want to promote a menu in designer to your class.

Comment: @drescherjm: It actually works. Now both menubar and toolbar are visible. But now there is an empty toolbar in front of the toolbar that I have created (probably because "addToolBar()" does not "reuse" existing toolbar like "menuBar()").

Comment: @drescherjm: I just realized that maybe I would be better off passing "self->ui->menuBar" and "self->ui->mainToolBar" to my class creating the menubar and toolbar (rather than "MainWindow") and then populate these existing UI-components. Would that work?